# If domain $R$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and $I$ is an integral ideal of $R$, have $R$ and $I$ the same rank as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

If an integral domain $R$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, do $R$ and $I$ have the same rank as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules? Assume $I$ is non-zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $R$ is of finite rank, then yes. If $a$ is a nonzero element of $I$, then $Ra$ is a free abelian group inside $I$ of rank equal to that of $R$, so that $I$ has rank at least equal to that of $R$. As it has rank at most equal to that of $R$, we have equality.

Comment: The same argument works in the infinite case, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I believe so. Let $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ be a $\Bbb Z$-basis for $R$, and let $w\in I$, nonzero element. Then $\{wb_i\}$ are still $\Bbb Z$-linearly independent, so the rank of $I$ is at least $n$. And at most $n$ as well, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside: through similar arguments offered by the other answers, one also has the result hold for nonzero fractional ideals $I$ of $R$.